# Jquery - finding values of radio buttons and changing the css of another element

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button group

```
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Yes />
<input type="radio" name="Q1" value="No />
```

I also have 2 divs

```
<div id="Q4" style="display:none"> Some content</div>
<div id="Q5" style="display:none"> Some content</div>
```

This is what I would like to do using Jquery

If someone clicks radio button with value Yes - set  div id=Q4 to display:block.
If someone clicks radio button with value No - set div id=Q4 to display:none and set div id=Q5 display:block

I have been trying and not very successful. I have used alerts in the jQuery to try and understand what I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
var userClick= $('input:radio[name=Q1]:checked').val();
switch(userClick){
  case 'Yes':
alert('Number1');
   case 'No':
     alert('Number2');    
  }
});
```

Comment: <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="Yes />
The double quote at the end of the value tag is missing?

Comment: What happens currently? Do you get your alerts happening?

Comment: Will you be using this for multiple radio button/div groups or just this one?

Comment: Your switch/case is missing `break`s.

Comment: @j08691 - I realised that was what I was missing. Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    var value = this.value;

    if (value === "Yes") {
        $("#Q4").css("display", "block");
        $("#Q5").css("display", "none");
    }
    else {
        $("#Q5").css("display", "block");
        $("#Q4").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Here's a nice working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/byvvx/

Comment: Excellent - thanks. I did manage to do it using switch but yours in also very neat. http://jsfiddle.net/nirmminator/Pe9Nm/43/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `change` event handler on the radio buttons using the **name** property of the checkboxes and handle the display. Something like this:

```
$("input[@name='Q1']").change(function(){
    var selected = this.value;

    if (selected === "Yes") {
        $("#Q5").css("display", "none");
        $("#Q4").css("display", "block");            
    }
    else {
        $("#Q4").css("display", "none");
        $("#Q5").css("display", "block");   
    }
});
```

And also double quotes at the end of value are missing in checkboxes. Hope this is just a ty[o in the questions only. otherwise please correct that also.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use jQuery's show() and hide() methods to show your divs.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var userClick= $('input:radio[name=Q1]:checked').val();

        if(userClick === "Yes") {
            $("#Q4").show();
            $("#Q5").hide();
        } else if(userClick === "No") {
            $("#Q5").show();
            $("#Q4").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do what you're describing:

```
$('input[name=Q1]').click(function () {
    $('#Q4,#Q5').hide();
    if ($(this).val() == "Yes") $('#Q4').show();
    if ($(this).val() == "No") $('#Q5').show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hPhmK/)**